# R: need to replace invisible/accented characters with regex

Tags: regex, r, encoding, gsub

I'm working with a file generated from several different machines that had different locale-settings, so I ended up with a column of a data frame with different writings for the same word:

```
CÃ“RDOBA
CÓRDOBA
CÒRDOBA
```

I'd like to convert all those to `CORDOBA`. I've tried doing

```
t<-gsub("Ã“|Ó|Ã’|Â°|°|Ò","O",t,ignore.case = T) # t is the vector of names
```

Wich works until it finds some "invisible" characters:
[image: Invisible Characters]

As you can see, I'm not able to see, in R, the additional charater that lies between `Ã` and `\` (If I copy-paste to MS Word, word shows it with an empty rectangle). I've tried to `dput` the vector, but it shows exactly as in screen (without the "invisible" character).

I ran `Encoding(t)`, and ir returns `unknown` for all values.

My system configuration follows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Colombia.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Colombia.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Colombia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                     
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Colombia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] zoo_1.7-12       dplyr_0.4.2      data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] R6_2.1.0        assertthat_0.1  magrittr_1.5    plyr_1.8.3      parallel_3.2.1  DBI_0.3.1       tools_3.2.1     reshape2_1.4.1  Rcpp_0.11.6     stringi_0.5-5  
[11] grid_3.2.1      stringr_1.0.0   chron_2.3-47    lattice_0.20-31
```

I've `saveRDS` a file with a data frame of actual and expected toy values, wich could be `loadRDS` from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbsbsqhv3biutdz/inv_char.Rdata?dl=0). I'm not absolutely sure it will load with the same problems I have (depending on you locale), but I hope it does, so you can provide some help.

At the end, I'd like to convert all those special characters to unaccented ones (`Ó` to `O`, etc.), hopefully without having to manually input each one of the special ones into a regex (in other words, I'd like --if possible-- some sort of `gsub("[:weird:]","[:equivalentToWeird:]",t)`. If not possible, at least I'd like to be able to find (and replace) those "invisible" characters.

Thanks,

**############## EDIT TO ADD ###################**

If I run the following code:

```
d<-readRDS("c:/path/to(downloaded/Dropbox/file/inv_char.Rdata")
stri_escape_unicode(d$actual)
```

This is what I get:

```
[1] "\\u00c3\\u201cN  N\\u00c2\\u00b0 08 \\\"CACIQUE CALARC\\u00c3\\u0081\\\" - ARMENIA"
[2] "\\u00d3N  N\\u00b0 08 \\\"CACIQUE CALARC\\u00c1\\\" - ARMENIA"                     
[3] "\\u00d3N  N\\u00b0 08 \\\"CACIQUE CALARC\\u00c1\\\" - ARMENIA(ALTERNO)"
```

Normal output is:

```
> d$actual
[1] Ã“N  NÂ° 08 "CACIQUE CALARCÃ" - ARMENIA       ÓN  N° 08 "CACIQUE CALARCÁ" - ARMENIA          ÓN  N° 08 "CACIQUE CALARCÁ" - ARMENIA(ALTERNO)
```

Comment: Are you able to post to Dropbox a sample of the original file that you loaded into R?

Comment: the `useBytes` argument might be useful.

Comment: Will try to do as soon as I can get back to the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @hadley, who pointed me towards `stringi`, I ended up discovering the offending characters and replacing them. This was my initial attempt:

```
unweird<-function(t){
    t<-stri_escape_unicode(t)
    t<-gsub("\\\\u00c3\\\\u0081|\\\\u00c1","A",t)
    t<-gsub("\\\\u00c3\\\\u02c6|\\\\u00c3\\\\u2030|\\\\u00c9|\\\\u00c8","E",t)
    t<-gsub("\\\\u00c3\\\\u0152|\\\\u00c3\\\\u008d|\\\\u00cd|\\\\u00cc","I",t)
    t<-gsub("\\\\u00c3\\\\u2019|\\\\u00c3\\\\u201c|\\\\u00c2\\\\u00b0|\\\\u00d3|\\\\u00b0|\\\\u00d2|\\\\u00ba|\\\\u00c2\\\\u00ba","O",t)
    t<-gsub("\\\\u00c3\\\\u2018|\\\\u00d1","N",t)
    t<-gsub("\\u00a0|\\u00c2\\u00a0","",t)
    t<-gsub("\\\\u00f3","o",t)
    t<-stri_unescape_unicode(t)
}
```

which produced the expected result. I was a little bit curious about other `stringi` functions, so I wondered if its substitution one could be faster on my 3.3 million rows. I then tried `stri_replace_all_regex` like this:

```
stri_unweird<-function(t){
  stri_unescape_unicode(stri_replace_all_regex(stri_escape_unicode(t),
    c("\\\\u00c3\\\\u0081|\\\\u00c1",
      "\\\\u00c3\\\\u02c6|\\\\u00c3\\\\u2030|\\\\u00c9|\\\\u00c8",
      "\\\\u00c3\\\\u0152|\\\\u00c3\\\\u008d|\\\\u00cd|\\\\u00cc",
      "\\\\u00c3\\\\u2019|\\\\u00c3\\\\u201c|\\\\u00c2\\\\u00b0|\\\\u00d3|\\\\u00b0|\\\\u00d2|\\\\u00ba|\\\\u00c2\\\\u00ba",
      "\\\\u00c3\\\\u2018|\\\\u00d1",
      "\\u00a0|\\u00c2\\u00a0",
      "\\\\u00f3"),
   c("A","E","I","O","N","","o"),
   vectorize_all = F))
}
```

As a side note, I ran `microbenchmark` on both methods, these are the results:

```
g<-microbenchmark(unweird(t),stri_unweird(t),times = 100L)
summary(g)
       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
1 423.0083 425.6400 431.9609 428.1031 432.6295 490.7658   100   b
2 118.5831 119.5057 121.2378 120.3550 121.8602 138.3111   100  a
```