# R read.csv breaks on special symbol

Tags: r, csv, encoding

I'm trying to parse UTF-8 file, but R parser can't read strings after this symbol [image: arrow symbol] (I've captured a screenshot, because it doesn't pastes to browser)

```
d <- read.csv2('myfile.csv', header = FALSE, sep=",", quote="\"", numerals='no.loss', encoding="UTF-8", skipNul=TRUE)
tail(d)[,]
```

[image: screenshot from notepad]

[image: screenshot of tail(d)[,] in RStudio]

Is there any way to remove this symbols from file?

**UPD:** vi shows this symbol as **^Z**
**UPD2:** link to example file https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kucjnia8ew1u5n/1.csv?dl=0

Comment: It would be useful to save a copy of a dummy csv file in the cloud, so potential answerers can play with your data

Comment: I don't know. You could try using `fread` from `data.table`, see if the problem persists/`fread` has a clever solution for it.

Comment: Are you sure the file is UTF-encoded? What OS are you on? How did you generate/acquire the file?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes. It is UTF-8 w/o BOM, writed by python 3 script in ubuntu (parsed data). Now I'm using it on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @MrFlick iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 generates the same file

Comment: iconv on your unix machine? How did you transfer it to your windows machine? It would really help if you could share the exact bytes of that line. Does `readLines()` read the file? Can you `charToRaw()` on that line so we can see the bytes?

Comment: iconv on windows via MINGW. I've added dropbox.com link to this line.

Comment: along with @MrFlick you can `readLines` and then get a hand from `stringi::stri_escape_unicode()` and companion `stri_unescape_unicode()` to be able to view and then remove those elements. You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230344/r-need-to-replace-invisible-accented-characters-with-regex

Comment: Still can't reproduce your problem even with your file... `read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kucjnia8ew1u5n/1.csv?raw=1", 
          encoding="UTF-8", skipNul=TRUE, header=FALSE)`

Answer (score -1):

I get just a warning if follow the code proposed by @cory:

```
read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kucjnia8ew1u5n/1.csv?raw=1", encoding="UTF-8", skipNul=TRUE, header=FALSE)

## Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kucjnia8ew1u5n/1.csv?raw=1'
```

But the actual data loads just in the same fashion as your csv. (look at the culprit, a `\032` character).

So here's an alternative code to avoid the warning:

```
a <- readChar("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kucjnia8ew1u5n/1.csv?raw=1",
               useBytes = TRUE, 
               nchars = 1000)
b <- gsub("\\\032", " ", a)
new_a <- read.table(header = FALSE, text = b, sep = ",")
```